# Plotting one scatterplot with multiple dataframes with ggplot in python

Tags: python, r, python-ggplot

I am trying to get data from two separate dataframes onto the same scatterplot. I have seen solutions in R that use something like:

`ggplot() + geom_point(data = df1, aes(df1.x,df2.y)) + geom_point(data = df2,aes(df2.x, df2.y))`

But in python, with the `ggplot` module, I get errors when I try to use `ggplot()` with no args. Is this just a limitation of the module? I know I can likely use another tool to do the plotting but I would prefer a ggplot solution if possible.

My first data frame consists of Voltage information every 2 minutes and temperature information every one hour, so combining the two dataframes is not 1 to 1. Also, I would prefer to stick with Python because the rest of my solution is in python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just giving one dataframe as argument for ggplot() and the other inside the second geom_point declaration should do the work:

```
ggplot(aes(x='x', y='y'), data=df1) + geom_point() + 
       geom_point(aes(x='x', y='y'), data=df2)
```

(I prefer using the column name notation, I think is more elegant, but this is just a personal preference)

Comment: That works, thank you. So, the 'base' ggplot needs its own dataset and subsequent geom_point() usages can add different datasets. Is that the gist of it?

Comment: It also surprised me the first time I realised about that. I don't really know the reason behind not allowing an empty ggplot() and including data in subsequent geom_point(). Maybe one of the main developers of the project could answer this better.

Comment: I think the error on an empty `ggplot()` call comes from the time where it wasn't allowed to specify a new df in each geom.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me with ggplot 0.11.2. I get `ValueError: First argument must be a sequence`. The first `ggplot(...)+geom_point()` part is working, the second `geom_point(aes(...), data = df2)` part is also working, but I can't `+` the two